# Is it possible to store user input into an html file with a table?

Tags: php, html, database

I have a html form set up and would like to save the inputted data into an html file. I know its possible with a .txt file but its unorganized. Ideally the html file would have a table that saves each input into a new row.

Comment: create a html string how you want it and write it to a file

Comment: you realize that html is just text as well? Don't store "formatted" data in html. html is not a storage format. It's a MARKUP format. You'd be better off with XML, or a database.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You basically build the `<tr` in the form processor, and insert it to the HTML file by using fopen(), fwrite(), etc... But as said, it's much better if you store only the data somewhere and build the HTML when needed. What actually do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jTable](http://www.jtable.org/) allows you to store data to a table on a webpage and at the same time send it to a server using ajax for persistent storage.